# Increase number of posts in a label page?

Tags: html, css, blogger, posts

According to many websites, it appears blogger will only allow us to post 20 unique labels to a page. This is the URL:

www.BLOG.com/search/label/This-is-the-label-page-that-displays-only-20-posts/

Is there any workaround that anyone knows of that will allow me to display all my posts that have a unique label? Currently, it only shows 20 posts per page, making finding content difficult for viewers.

I've followed a number of tutorials like this one, but no luck. http://www.allblogtools.com/tricks-and-hacks/changing-maximum-number-of-posts-in-blogger-label-page/
Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this, in fact, is using the *max-results* URL params in the link to label pages:

blog.blogspot.com/search/label/[label]**?max-results=INT**

where INT is an integer (500 max).

However, Blogger platform would probably not display the specified number of results in most cases.

Why?

Blogger have a server-side feature named "[Autopagination](https://blogger.googleblog.com/2010/02/auto-pagination-on-blogger.html)":

> Blogger dynamically adjust how much content to send to the browser
>   depending on (a) the amount of HTML on the page being requested (in
>   kilobytes) and (b) the number of images on the page

So a good suggestion consist in optimizing you content (take a look for example at [Google PageSpeed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/)).

Another approach could be editing the blog template to change the display of the posts in the label search pages using [data tags](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/46995?hl=en), for example, displaying "*lightweight*" results with only the titles of each post with a default thumbnail and a default summary or just the post title.

Answer (score 0):

I added a page break at the beginning of some long posts I had (with many images)  in my blog ([the mobile spoon](https://www.mobilespoon.net)) and to my surprise it worked!

The number of posts per page grew up significantly (also in the home page).